# iOS - Apple TV - Detect show on Apple TV programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, airplay, uiscreen, apple-tv

How can i detect showing on Apple TV?

I've tried already to detect num of screens:

```
[[UIScreen screens] count]
```

But it remains on 1.

I've tried also to listen to an event:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(screenDidConnect:)
                                             name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

But the event never fire.

Any tips/tricks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly - but is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272223/is-there-any-notification-for-detecting-airplay-in-objective-c?

Comment: Not exactly, The above question/answer talk about detect airPlay available, and that's all. I need to detect when the user actually show the movie on AppleTV (airPlay). Any idea?

Comment: So you have a MPMMoviePlayerController, the user clicks the Airplay button and it runs on the Apple TV. What and how the user interacts is probably hard to detect as the stream is handled completely by the AppleTV (just disconnect your device from the wifi and you will see that the stream still runs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer!

As simple as it could be:

Just do:

```
self.moviePlayer.isAirPlayVideoActive
```

It will return me whether the AirPlay is active/not active.

Thanks @rist